# How to find boundary pixels of each connected component in an image in opencv

Tags: c, matlab, opencv

I have an image with text and I want to find boundary pixels of every connected component.Which method should I use in opencv 2.3,I am coding in c.
This function may be just like bwboundaries of matlab.

thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In OpenCV 2.3, the function you want is called [cv::findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv.FindContours). Each contour (which is the boundary of the connected component) is stored as a vector of points. Here's how to access the contours in C++:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(img, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
{
    // do something with the current contour
    // for instance, find its bounding rectangle
    Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    // ...
}
```

If you need the full hierarchy of contours, including holes inside components and so forth, the call to findContours is like this:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
Hierarchy hierarchy;
cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
// do something with the contours
// ...
```

**Note:** the parameter `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` indicates that straight line segments in the contour will be encoded by their end-points. If instead you want all contour points to be stored, use `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`.

**Edit:** in C you call `cvFindContours` and access the contours like this:

```
CvSeq *contours;
CvMemStorage* storage;
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvFindContours(img, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
CvSeq* c;
for(c=contours; c != NULL; c=c->h_next)
{
    // do something with the contour
    CvRect r = cvBoundingRect(c, 0);
    // ...
}
```

`c->h_next` points to the next contour at the same level of the hierarchy as the current contour, and `c->v_next` points to the first contour inside the current contour, if there is any. Of course, if you use `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` like above, `c->v_next` will always be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I am doing this in C.So I will have to use cvFindContours.Any suggestions for this.?

Comment: How can I colorize the ROI delimited by the contour?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cvFindContours (this is the version 1.0 call, but there should be a similar call in 2.3)

Comment: Thanks I found it in 2.3 also.Can you please explain what does CvSeq ** means in this?

Comment: each CvSeq* structure stores a connected component.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such function implemented in OpenCV.
You should either searching into morphology operations (substractions of your image and the same one dilated) or have a look at the cvbloblib 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

It has been developed for this very purpose ;).

Comment: Well, perhaps in reading cvbloblib code examples ? I gave you the link already :)

Comment: I call it unfair. There is a code sample at the very end of the web page. I would gladly help someone that searched a bit to solve his problem. There are tons of information about findcontours and cvbloblib on the web, none appear in user1140170's questions